# How can we promote the activities of newcomers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, new-users

I think giving some opportunities to the newcomers to get in touch with the Stack Overflow family will be of great advancement to the system. My suggestions are

- We can reserve some sort of but live questions to allow newcomers earn some reputation points.
- Also reward some badges based on that.
- Send mails to them with samples of best answers focusing on its construction
- Also urge them to post questions in the best way since I see so many non-formatted questions posted by newbies.

I would like to know how can we do this within Stack Overflow. Some nice suggestions from existing experienced members will be really encouraging.

Comment: Familiarity comes with experience and I want to promote that part by making novice more in touch with the site and its think tank.

Comment: Newcomers have world of opportunities out there. Is there a problem to solve? I would not particularly like my questions to only be shown to an exclusive group for example.

Comment: How about some kind of welcome package as an email with links to SO FAQs and already extensive pages about asking questions, formatting, etc?

Comment: I can dig the idea to provide an analysis of a concrete example of a good answer. It's one thing to tell them to keep it concise and to the point but if you give a few examples with some common mistakes, overall quality will rise.

Comment: *Most new comers are students and freshers to IT industry*.  So we must have a way to welcome them.

Comment: That is exactly I want to point out. We must promote them not by giving points but urging them to earn it. Also it will be nice to create a healthy way to interact.

Comment: As a student of old we were taught to research first and then ask questions. I would hope new students do the same.

Comment: @jozxyqk We *already* do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We can reserve some sort of but live questions

We already have this.  It's chat.

> Send mails to them with samples of best answers focusing on its construction

If users want to see great answers they need only look through the site a bit.  They're not hard to find at all.  They can look through the questions list sorting by votes, for example.

> Also urge them to post questions in the best way since I see so many non-formatted questions posted by newbies.

We attempt to do this in many ways already.  Users cannot post a question at all unless they have verified that they have read the "How to Ask" page.  At the end of the day many users are simply uninterested in our attempts to help them ask better questions, and will disregard everything we put in their way to help them.  If you have some specific suggestion to improve the question quality of new users, then by all means, post it, but saying, "make people post better questions" is entirely unhelpful.  If we knew how to do that we'd have done it.  The point is that its *really* hard to get many users to post good questions.

Comment: Is there any option to link social web sites or community websites and publish the achievements and nice things happening within Stalk-overflow community?

Comment: @Anoop Sure.  Users are encouraged to share their own posts on social networks, and there are handy tools in the site to conveniently do so.  SE also has a twitter account that they post news or interesting questions to.